# send message from java program to activemq using mule

Tags: java, activemq-classic, mule

Iam trying to send a string message from a java program to queue in ActiveMQ using MULE.Iam new to mule this is my mule-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms"
      xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.0.xsd
      http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/3.1/mule-jms.xsd
      http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.1/mule.xsd">


<jms:activemq-connector name="jmsConnector" 
    specification="1.1" 
    brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" />
<model name="jmsModel">
    <service name="jmsService">
        <inbound>

        </inbound>
        <outbound>
            <pass-through-router>
                <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="myQueue" />
            </pass-through-router>
        </outbound>
    </service>
</model>
</mule>
```

and following is my java class

```
public class MuleCaller {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        MuleCaller springCaller = new MuleCaller();
        springCaller.runListner();
        //  spAsync.onMessage(null);
}
public void runListner(){

    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {
            "mule-config.xml"
        });

    }
```

What are the mistakes here, and iam not clear what to be written in

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 3):

This is based on an older Mule version (3.1.2) and is using flow syntax

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.1/mule.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/3.1/mule-jms.xsd">

<jms:activemq-connector name="jmsConnector"  
    brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616"
    specification="1.1"
    maxRedelivery="30"
    disableTemporaryReplyToDestinations="true"
    createMultipleTransactedReceivers="true"
    acknowledgementMode="CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE"
    numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers="1"
    persistentDelivery="true">
</jms:activemq-connector>

<flow name="inbound JMS service">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="jmsConnector" queue="/jmsQueue" exchange-pattern="one-way">
        <jms:transaction action="BEGIN_OR_JOIN"/>
    </jms:inbound-endpoint>

    <echo-component/>
</flow>
```

Using the ActiveMQ console you can create a queue called `jmsQueue` and manually send messages to it.  A Mule process using the config above should print out whatever text is in the message you place on the queue.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there is a connector-ref attribute of the jms:outbound-endpoint tag that you should likely use to specific to where outbound messages are to go. 
like this:

```
<jms:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="jmsConnection" queue="myQueue" />
```

Secondly, without an inbound route, i've no clue what data is to be operated on by your service. try to go through some more of the example.